# MySQL top-N ranking for each group, based on latest group's rows

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate, top-n

For each group of `TS`, there's random number of rows that having different `Name` and it's `Count`. I would like to do the following:

1. Get latest group of TIMESTAMP with NAME order desc by `Count`. For more than 3 rows in the latest group, the rest sum by `Count` and rename as "Other".
2. For each of the `TIMESTAMP` group, find rows having `NAME` in step 1.
3. If not found, 0 padding as `Count` for the pair in specific group.

Have a look at the illustration:

```
TS         | Name     | Count
=============================
1552286160 | Apple    | 7
1552286160 | Orange   | 8
1552286160 | Grape    | 8
1552286160 | Pear     | 9
1552286160 | Kiwi     | 10
1552286160 | Berry    | 3
1552286160 | Carrot   | 2

1552286100 | Apple    | 10
1552286100 | Orange   | 12
1552286100 | Grape    | 14
1552286100 | Pear     | 16
1552286100 | Kiwi     | 9

1552286040 | Apple    | 4

1552285980 | Peach    | 8
```

With this dataset, I would like to have the following:

```
TS         | Name     | Count
=============================
1552286160 | Kiwi     | 10
1552286160 | Pear     | 9
1552286160 | Grape    | 8
1552286160 | Other    | 8 + 7 + 3 + 2

1552286100 | Kiwi     | 9
1552286100 | Pear     | 16
1552286100 | Grape    | 14
1552286100 | Other    | 10 + 9

1552286040 | Kiwi     | 0
1552286040 | Pear     | 0
1552286040 | Grape    | 0
1552286040 | Other    | 4

1552286040 | Kiwi     | 0
1552286040 | Pear     | 0
1552286040 | Grape    | 0
1552286040 | Other    | 8
```

This is actually an extended solution came from [MySQL top-N ranking and sum the rest of same group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55098157/mysql-top-n-ranking-and-sum-the-rest-of-same-group) However, the solution does not group each `TS` group with the same rows from the latest `TS` group, in this case `TS=1552286160`.

The SQL Fiddle that I've prepared is located here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e13004/1

Thanks if you have any idea.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using MySQL 8+ or later if you think you will have to write queries like this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the previous answer was deleted? No worries, I will not flag down anyone that provides a suggestion even it's wrong, a good discussion is much valuable than a solution.

Comment: Yes, I deleted it, because it is somewhat far from what you need. I don't see a very clean way of doing this, because you might have to generate the "others" records in the result set.